# Petapoco - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Tags: petapoco

While trying to use

`_database.Delete(pocoObjects);`

I get the error:
Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: key

Answer (score 0):

I should have been able to tell by the name, but I didn't realize the petapoco object I was trying to delete was a list.

Instead of:
`_database.Delete(pocoObjects);`

I should be using:
`pocoObjects.ForEach(entity => database.Delete(entity));`